# How do I figure out what speech to text model is being used?

Tags: dialogflow-es, speech-to-text

I have a dialogflow ES bot where google does speech to text, which happens before the dialogflow request is sent to Dialogflow fulfillment. We have auto speech adaption setup in the dialogflow ES agent settings. I was wondering what transcription model is being use. The following page talks about transcription: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/transcription-model

Is there a way to figure out what transcription model is being used? I don't see a setting in the dialogflow agent or in google project. Judging from the behavior, I would say we are probably using latest_short.

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow uses Google Cloud's Speech-to-Text service for speech recognition. The transcription model used by Google Cloud Speech-to-Text can be configured, but it's typically set to use the latest available model for best performance. In your case, you mentioned that you suspect it might be using the "latest_short" model.

Speech-to-text picks what best suits the settings of your request when you don't specify your model field with the model name.

> "Note: If you don't specify a model to use for speech recognition, Speech-to-Text attempts to select the model that best fits the settings in the RecognitionConfig of your request."

You can experiment by making requests using different models and comparing the results. This can give you insights into which model might be suitable for your use case.

If you can't find the information in the Dialogflow or Google Cloud Console settings, you may consider reaching out to Google Cloud Support. They should be able to provide you with information about the specific transcription model being used for your project. You can also file an [issue or a feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list).